Externalize strings. What does it mean in Anylogic when try to make own jar library?
Does anybody know what does this option means and what does it affect?
I export library with and without this option and doesn’t see any differences.
I look at Anylogic help, and doesn’t found any explanations about this option.
Anylogic window with such option

It is quite irrelevant and just a "leftover" from the Eclipse underlying structure.
It allows you to apply different model languages to your library block properties, but you need to set things up correctly for that (iirc)
Never used it, never needed it :)

Benjamin, This is very interesting for me because my jar is configured in two languages: English and any other. And now I have to write every system message like this
String message = isEng?”Lets speak in English”:”Lets speak in other language”;
Could you tell me where to look (explore) are these special model settings to correctly adjust the appearance of the message?

no idea, google String externalization. But pls report back here (you can answer your own question) for future users :)
